# WinDBG doesn't stop at process entry point

Tags: assembly, windbg

I'm trying to use WinDBG and wrote a simple hello world in ASM (running on Windows XP).

Now I was a bit surprised, when I run it, that WinDBG always stops in ntdll when I load the process:

```
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
7c90120e cc              int     3
7c90120f c3              ret
```

Normally I would expect that a debugger stops at the first instruction of the new process, not somewhere in the kernel. Now I can use:

```
bp start
```

where `start` is my entry point. But I have to do this always manually. Is there some way to instruct WinDBG that it should start debugging in my program and not somehwere else? Why doesn't it do this automatically? I noticed the same behaviour from GDB as well, but at least GDB automtatically seems to set a breakpint in `main()` (for C programs at least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [workspace](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2010/05/07/uncovering-how-workspaces-work-in-windbg.aspx) should save your breakpoint so you should not need to enter it next time.

The only way I can think to achieve what you want is by passing a command line argument when starting windbg:

```
windbg -g "C:\myApp\myapp.exe"
```

This tells windbg to ignore the initial breakpoint in `ntdll` and then it should hit your breakpoint in `start`.

Comment: Thanks. I take a look at this by using a local workspace. As to the commandline, thisis not possible, for two reeasons: 1. windbg is loaded from an IDE. 2. When I reload the image file, the breakpoints are gone as well. Reloading, resets the workspace? So when I define a breakpoint and save it with the worksapce, then the bp will perists even after `.reload`? (I give it a try).

Comment: @Devolus not sure why the breakpoint is not persisting, you can save your workspace and then load it during the session via the menu or command line `-W`, not sure how you start WinDbg via IDE but you can still pass the command line argument, it is important if you do this that the exe you are starting (if you are opening an exe and not attaching to a running process) is the last argument.

Comment: I give it a try tonight. I'm just starting using Windbg, as I previously used SoftICE (which no longer exists) or VisualStudio and gdb. So I guess I have some starting difficulties. For the IDE I try to find out how it runs the debugger.

Comment: @Devolus Use `bu` instead of `bp`. From the debugger.chm that comes with windbg: "Breakpoints that you set with bp are not saved in WinDbg workspaces. Breakpoints that are set with bu are saved in workspaces."

Answer (score 1):

When a debugger in Windows is starting up then the program is not stopped at the entry point but at the startup code in the system DLLs that is executed BEFORE the entry point!

(However it is uncommon that the debugger first stops at DbgBreakPoint!)

When you stop an already running process then a new thread is created that calls DbgBreakPoint. The debugger than stops at that address.